# ldconfig seems no functional under alpine 3.3

Tags: dockerfile, alpine-linux

I'm currently install the goczmq (https://github.com/zeromq/goczmq) on golang:1.6.2-alpine docker container, as following:

```
wget https://download.libsodium.org/libsodium/releases/libsodium-1.0.10.tar.gz
wget https://download.libsodium.org/libsodium/releases/libsodium-1.0.10.tar.gz.sig
wget https://download.libsodium.org/jedi.gpg.asc
gpg --import jedi.gpg.asc
gpg --verify libsodium-1.0.10.tar.gz.sig libsodium-1.0.10.tar.gz
tar zxvf libsodium-1.0.10.tar.gz
cd libsodium-1.010.
./configure; make check
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

The process failed on `ldconfig`, there seems be a command `ldconfig`, but  I don't think it is actually functional. Any insights? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 21):

Alpine's [version of ldconfig](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86/musl-utils) requires you to specify the target folder or library as an argument. Note that alpine has no /etc/ld.so.conf file, nor does it recognize one if you create it.

Example with no target path:

```
$ docker run -ti alpine sh -c "ldconfig; echo \$?"
1
```

Example with target path:

```
$ docker run -ti alpine sh -c "ldconfig /; echo \$?"
0
```

However, even with that there are frequently linking errors. Others suggest:

- Manual symbolic links
- [Installing glibc](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/11) into your container.

Comment: For reference: alpine does not use /etc/ld.so.conf, but can use a similar file named /etc/ld-musl-$(ARCH).path, i.e. /etc/ld-musl-x86_64.path. _if present, this will be processed as a text file containing the shared library search path, with components delimited by newlines or colons. If absent, a default path of "/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib" will be used._ - https://www.musl-libc.org/doc/1.0.0/manual.html